# How to remove unused ports from AWS load balancer created by istio?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, istio

When i install istio in k8s, it create a load balancer in AWS. This loadbalancer are created with some ports, like 15020, 15029, 15030, etc... How i can remove unused ports from AWS Load Balancer? I don't use some port and i want to remove during the creation of the load balancer.

For example. If i want to remove the 15020 port. How i can do that?

I tried to edit some rules in helm-values.yaml, but without success.

I want to remove unused ports because i want to put some inbound rules into load balancer, but AWS have a limitation for each security group.

Here i show how i put inbound rules. Its works, but if i have many ports, AWS don`t acept all ip ranges that i desire.

```
gateways:
  istio-ingressgateway:
    loadBalancerSourceRanges: [10 IPRANGES]
```

Thank you.

Comment: you can do this using aws console/.

Comment: Hi. Yes I can. But as I said, I want to do this at the time of creating the load balancer. Because these rules will be managed by Helm. In that case, if I do not raise the threshold for the inbound rules in AWS, I will not be able to do this setup. Doing this management manually is not an option. As I put it in the example above, I have 10 blocks of ips, which I want to associate with about 15 ports, this gives 150 input rules. In short: I really need to remove unused ports, which are created by istio in the load balancer, and do not want to do this manually on aws console.
Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default ports in your values.yaml like so (listed ports are the defaults):

```
    gateways:
      istio-ingressgateway:
        enabled: true
        ports:
        - port: 15020
          targetPort: 15020
          name: status-port
        - port: 80
          targetPort: 80
          name: http2
          nodePort: 31380
        - port: 443
          name: https
          nodePort: 31390
        - port: 31400
          name: tcp
          nodePort: 31400
        - port: 15029
          targetPort: 15029
          name: https-kiali
        - port: 15030
          targetPort: 15030
          name: https-prometheus
        - port: 15031
          targetPort: 15031
          name: https-grafana
        - port: 15032
          targetPort: 15032
          name: https-tracing
        - port: 15443
          targetPort: 15443
          name: tls
```

See also for default configuration: https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/charts/gateways/values.yaml

Comment: Yes. It work`s. I`m not tried this before because i have the same definition rules in the gateway.yml, but yes, if i define this into values.yml, works. Thank you.